# <JavaScriptFunction> in <RibbonDiffXml> not working

Tags: javascript, xml, dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon

I created a custom button in the ribbon menua bar in CRM 2011 and now I want to call a webresource js.  This is what I have now:

```
<Actions>
    <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="functionName"
       Library="$webresource:opportunity_ribbon.js" />
</Actions>
```

But when I click the button, no response at all.  Any idea what's wrong?

**Update:**  The problem seems to be the js I'm calling.  The line

locAddActTo(4207);

fails and its says the value of locAddActTo is null.  Any ideas about how to fix this?

Comment: The XML looks good to me. I would only double check the function name and the name of the library, then debug the code with IE F12 developer tools to see if the code gets executed at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I debug using F12, I found the js function is indeed called, but there is a null reference.  My js only has one line: locAddActTo(4207);.  I'm not very familiar with locAddAct.  How does it work and what is 4207?

Comment: 4207 may be the `ObjectTypeCode` for the `Letter` entity. Is there a specific reason you're using `locAddActTo(4207)` in your code? And at this point, it might make more sense to detail what you want your code to accomplish.

Comment: I'm actually debugging other people's code.  I guess they just want to open up a new letter..?  Whatever they want to accomplish, I don't understand why locAddActTo is null.  From the examples I saw on various websites, I failed to see why this line dies.

Comment: According to this website: http://www.adaptds.com/issuetrackingblog/2009/02/27/is-your-crm-flexible-ms-dynamics-crm-vs-enterprisewizard/ the locAddActTo cases.js.  I would work on trying to figure out why that file isn't getting loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after I changed locAddActTo to locAddRelatedTo, but I don't know why is it.  Anyone?

Comment: We'd need to see the contents of that web resource to answer that

Comment: The webresource only has this one line: function xx() {locAddRelated(4207);}  This is called by <JavaScriptFunction> under <RibbonDiffXml> in isv.config of the form